# How to catch an exception in Java?

Tags: java, exception

How to catch an exception in Java? I have a program that accepts user input which is of integer value. Now if the user enters an invalid value, it throws a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`. How do I catch that exception?

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String str;
        int no;
        if (e.getSource() == bb) {
            str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter quantity");
            no = Integer.parseInt(str);
 ...
```

Comment: You need to read the whole stack trace.  Was this exception thrown in your code?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/ and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

Comment: Check here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: I hope you know the exception occurs, because the submitted number is too big to fit into an `int`.

Comment: How do you *actually* know the term `throw` and `catch` yet not knowing how to use Exceptions?

Answer (score 4):

```
try {
   int userValue = Integer.parseInt(aString);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   //there you go
}
```

and specifically in your code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String str;
    int no;
    //------------------------------------
    try {
       //lots of ifs here
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //do something with the exception you caught
    }

    if (e.getSource() == finish) {
        if (message.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter the Input First");
        } else {
            leftButtons();

        }
    }
    //rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Integer.parseInt`? :-)

Comment: yes it should. thats what i get for coding from memory :-)

Comment: or you can throw it and catch it in the calling function

Answer (score 0):

you have got try and catch blocks :

```
try {
    Integer.parseInt(yourString);
    // do whatever you want 
}
//can be a more specific exception aswell like NullPointer or NumberFormatException
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("wrong format");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try { 
    //codes that thows the exception
} catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
    e.printTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its worth mentioning that it is common for many programmers to catch an exception like so:

```
try
{
    //something
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Even if they know what the problem is or doesnt want to do anything in the catch clause. Its just good programming and can be a pretty useful diagnostic tool.