# How does one catch an exception thrown by the main method in java?

Tags: java, exception

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException {
  if (args[0].matches(".*\\w.*")) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't input characters!");
  }
  String input = insertSpaces(args[0]);
  args = input.split("\\s+");
  printAnswer(calculate(args),args);
}
```

In the above code, the main method throws an IllegalArgumentException. How do I catch the exception thrown from the main method? The reason I ask, and if I'm incorrect please correct me, is because my understanding is that when a method throws an exception, the caller of the method is responsible for catching the exception. The main method in this case has no other method calling it so I can't figure out how to catch the exception. I'm guessing the JVM is working behind the scenes to call the method but then how would I make the JVM catch the execption. Please provide CODE if possible along with explanation. Otherwise explain why not possible.

Comment: You don't throw an exception from the main method. You either handle it from main or simply exit the program.

Comment: If `main` throws an exception, the JVM by default catches it, prints the stack trace, and shuts down.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. Since an invalid input would shut down my program eventually, throwing an exception from my main method is just a way to make it terminate earlier since there is no way for me to manually catch it?

Comment: why not add an try-catch block in your main Method, which contains your code? This is what you want - just catch and handle it yourself(also as @JoeC has beautifully pointed out, once your main method throws an exception the JVM shuts down - so better catch it!)

Comment: @Japu_D_Cret I see, I will work on a solution that works around my problem and post it.

Comment: @EdmondWeiss see http://stackoverflow.com/q/14215694/3858121 for reference​ how to catch an exception

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is avoiding them on `main` method call and handle it and show user a meaningful message about what happened and decide continue or terminate. 
 As Joe C mentioned you can let it throw so JVM will handle and the user or caller will see the stack trace. When you make such a decision (using throws on main) it is the moment that you can do nothing about exception. i.e. you receive required file name as arg but file is not there. If you don`t do logging to external resources probably you want to let JVM print stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever throw an exception from the `main` method.

Don't ever let the `main` method crash from an exception.

`IllegalArgumentException`, like any runtime exception, is a result of the programmer messing up. Fix what you messed up.

Don't catch it, prevent it.

Comment: I have to disagree in this case. You say that IllegalArgumentException is a result of the programmer. In this case, a user not a programmer is entering values for the program. The job of the programmer is to ensure that a program works by guiding the user on how to properly utilize the program even if the user messes up instead of the program ending abruptly. The programmer thus makes the program adaptable and flexible.

Comment: In this case the OP is using the exception improperly, by not having it represent a programmer messup. In what way is throwing a runtime exception from `main` "guiding the user on how to properly utilize the program even if the user messes up instead of the program ending abruptly"?